# Model validate date format in c# asp.net web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am mapping the web api Get request complex type input parameter with a model and I want to validate the date format of the input type in the model.

My input uri is as follows
http://localhost:xxxx/api/games/?id=5&date=2018-01-17

In my GameController

```
public IHttpActionResult Get([FromUri]Gamedata) {

 if (ModelState.IsValid) {
 }
 else {

 }
}
```

In my model class

```
public class Game
    {
        [Required]
        public int? Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string date { get; set; } // Validate the date format "YYYY-MM-DD"


}
```

I would like to validate the date format "YYY-MM-DD". How this can be achieved? I am reading [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx). But don't know which is the annotation to be used?

Comment: Why don't you use DateTime object instead for string? then you can format the dateString based on locale na?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this

```
 [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
```

In your model

```
    public class Game
    {
        [Required]
        public int? Id { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
        public DateTime date { get; set; } // Validate the date format "YYYY-MM-DD"
     }
```

You can also look at [DateTime.GetDateTimeFormats Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyk2998w(v=vs.110).aspx)